Forgotten animated movie, creatures with heads like stingrays that get distracted by hats
There is a movie I remember watching as a kid and it's been driving me absolutely crazy for years not being able to find it. 
It could have been from the late 70s to the early 90s. I believe I watched it when I was 5-10 so the movie would be more than 16 years old. It was in English but I would have been too young to know if it was dubbed or not. 
It is an animated movie, around the animation time and style of Little Nemo. It is NOT Labyrinth, as some people have suggested this description close to the bog scene in that movie.
What I remember is there is a scene where the heroes are going through a forest or swamp and come across tall creatures (I believe wearing black) whose heads were shaped like orange or red sting-rays with 4 sharp teeth. 
These stingray creatures left their bodies and flew around and exchanged bodies. 
The eventually become distracted and the heroes are able to escape because there is a crate or chest full of hats belonging to one of the characters that the stingray creatures become enamoured with. I believe this scene took place in an arid dead forest, but I could be mistaken 
Those elements are clear in my memory, the other details are more vague, but I believe there was a boy trying to save or get to a girl or princess, being held by some kind of leader of a band of creatures similar to goblins (also not The Princess and the Goblin, I tried that movie too). 
I remember the style being similar in animation to Little Nemo hence me referencing it. I don't believe it was anime, so North American or European style. 

I gave as much as I can think of. Around the time of Little Nemo, but it could have been from the late 70s to the early 90s. I believe I watched it when I was 5-10 so the movie would be more than 16 years old. It was in English but I would have been too young to know if it was dubbed or not.

Edits added. I don't remeber the production company.

Could be Time Masters http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0084315/ or Fantastic Planet http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0070544/

Dang you had me going with time masters, some of the images looked familiar. But that's not it nor is it fantastic planet.

maybe it is Gandahar https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gzBHjfy7kR4

No not that. There's no way my dad would have let me watch something with nudity when I was a kid. This is driving me crazy. Lol

Is it Disney's The Rescuers?
The swampy forest reminds me esp. of this old animated classic.


We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

The above is not correct... How do I remove it as an answer?

@DorianKing There is no way to delete this answer, for better or worse it is the 'officially correct' answer now. : (

@DorianKing I can understand your concern but there is no need to remove it and it's not a spam. You can just leave a plain comment that it's not the one you looking for.
